# (Alternative solution) Issues with Anaconda install - Failed to create Anaconda menus

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently uninstalled Anaconda 3 as it was giving me issues but after installing it and trying to use the latest Anaconda3-2019.10 for Windows I got the "Failed to create Anaconda menus" error each time i installed.   I check PATHs, checked and cleaned registry and still not hope.

Comment: Define "issues".

Comment: package inconsistent messages, conda update --all didnt help, removing env was not working (didnt allow me to) etc

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Some how re-installing the exact same old version of **Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64** worked!

I cannot explain it.